# return code in the CGI while inserting into Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, perl, cgi

I have a Perl CGI script that inserts `value1`, `value2`, `value3` into an Oracle database

```
eval {

    my $sth = $dbh->prepare(
        "insert into $table (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3) VALUES ('$value1','$value2','$value3')"
    );

    if ( defined( $sth ) ) {
        $sth->execute();
    }
    else {
        die( "Sth not defined" );
    }
};

print "Successfully inserted";
```

For unique value1, value2, value3 I have no problem inserting these values, but if I try to insert duplicate values I am getting

> Unique Constraint violated Error on execute()

in the logs. But the page still says Successfully inserted.

So I was thinking if I can get the return code of

```
$sth->execute();
```

Then may be I can use that info to display whether it was successfully inserted or display that an error was encountered.

Or are there any other ways that I can use to display the error when duplicate data is being inserted?

Comment: Please show how you open/create your `$dbh`, especially the `RaiseError` and `PrintError` flags. Depending on them, an `execute or die` could help.

Comment: @PerlDuck: `die` is almost never the right thing to do in a web application. You should get a page of HTML out there no matter what happens.

Comment: @Borodin Yes, true. But he's doing it in `eval`. I just wanted to give an idea _where_ the error handling should happen. Nice hat, b.t.w. :-)

Comment: My phone doesn't show the hats and my neighbors are listening to loud weird music :-(

Comment: @PerlDuck: Thanks. I don't really know what it means :-/

Comment: *All around my hat I will wear the green willow;
And all around my hat for a twelve month and a day;
If anybody should ask me the reason why I'm wearing it;
It’s all for my true love who's far, far away.*

Comment: @Borodin [They say](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/just-here-for-the-hat) it's awarded when you _“own any hat while the entire site collectively has at least 20 distinct hats”_. To me that sounds like "you get a hat because you already have a hat". I have one too, but prefer to wear my halfmoon shaped one. Don't know why I received it, perhaps for participating here after sunset.

Answer (score 3):

It's not useful to `die` inside CGI code. You're supposed to be generating an HTML response page, and just giving up half-way through isn't a useful thing to do

Similarly, you don't want to enable the `RaiseError` option in yuour DBI connection, which is simply asking DBI to `die` for you if it encounters an error

If you don't `die` or have `RaiseError` enabled, then you don't need `eval`

It's useful to enable `PrintError`, which gets DBI to use `warn` to record the same message. That will appear in the server log file for later diagnosis

A call to `$sth->execute` will return a *false* value if it fails, and on that basis you can print an error message together with the error string

You should also use *placeholders* in your `prepare` statement. It's simply a matter of putting question marks `?` in place of the column values and passing the real values in your call to `execute`

The logic should look something like this

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pass, { RaiseError => 0, PrintError => 1 });

my $sth = $dbh->prepare( "insert into $table (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)" );

if ( $sth ) {

    my $ret = $sth->execute( $value1, $value2, $value3 );

    if ( $ret ) {
        print "Successfully inserted\n";
    }
    else {
        print "Insert failed:\n";
        print $sth->errstr, "\n";
    }
}
else {
    print "Failed to prepare statement handle:\n";
    print $dbh->errstr, "\n";
}
```